# How to use DontSaveSensitive and xml configuration file during SSIS package development

Tags: ssis, configuration-files

Is it somhow possible to set the **ProtectionLevel of SSIS package to DontSaveSensitive** and to **use connection string with password from configuration file during package development in Visual Studio**?

I have package e.g. **Package1 with ProtectionLevel = DontSaveSensitive**. This package is using connection from connection manager e.g. **Connection1**.

**Package1 has configuration enabled** using configuration file **file1.dtsConfig** with connection string specified. **This connection string has the password in it:**

```xml
<DTSConfiguration>
    <DTSConfigurationHeading>
        <DTSConfigurationFileInfo GeneratedBy="..." GeneratedFromPackageName="..." GeneratedFromPackageID="..." GeneratedDate="20.3.2013 12:08:27"/>
    </DTSConfigurationHeading>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[Destination].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=.;Password=Password123;User ID=MyUser;Initial Catalog=Catalog;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
</DTSConfiguration>
```

Now when opening the connection from connection manager in Visual Studio, the **text field for Password is left blank** and the package doen't execute. **Why wasn't used the password specified within the connection string in configuration file file1.dtsConfig?**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally we found a way how to do it:

- Change ProtectionLevel to **DontSaveSensitive**
- Create configuraton file with connection string
- Manually edit this configuration file: add the password to the connection string in case you connect with SQL Server authentication

Then SSIS package will load the connection string inclusive password from the configuration file even in Visual Studio. In connection manager-connection dialog the password will not be shown, but the package runs using connection string from configuration.

Comment: The problem with using `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey` is when you share your package to some one else or some other user tries to run your package ,the execution will `fail` . This option should be used when you don't have plan to deploy your package or integrate your package with your team or giving permission to other user to run your package when u deploy it in sql server or file system

Comment: Well but I am using packages cretaed by another user on another PC with settings EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey on my PC right now. When i specified the configuration file, then the connection string is now read from the config (not from the package) and package runs ok even the protection level is set to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey and I am not the author of the package.

Comment: That seems weird . check this article out http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2091/securing-your-ssis-packages-using-package-protection-level/

Comment: I read this post before posting this question on SO. Its good article, but it dosn't say anything about ProtectionLevel when package configuration is enabled. Here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc895212.aspx you can read: "When you add configurations to a package, you are basically exposing package properties and allowing them to be updated with a new value that comes from a file ...". If you "expose" connection strings and manually add passwords to them in config file then those connection string will be used. I will do some more tests tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

SSIS will take the connection string from the `Config File` only during the `runtime`.Even if you mark the checkbox `Save my Password` , SSIS won't save the password value.This option is vald only during the `BIDS session`. So the next time when you open the package using `BIDS` ,again you need to enter the credentials in `Visual Studio` else the package won't `compile` ,But the package will always execute properly during `run time` if you have specified the `connection string` in `config file`.

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141747.aspx) it clearly states that

> Do not save sensitive : prevents properties that are marked sensitive
>   from  being saved with the package and therefore makes the sensitive
>   data unavailable to other users.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case also when package has been set at first to use EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey, then changed to DontSaveSensitive -protection level. You must manually edit .conmgr-file and remove DTS:Password element and put the password into connection string, as user **dee** has wisely written above.